# Finding integer points on elliptic curves via divisibility conditions like $(a+b)^2 \mid (2b^3+6ab^2-1)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is the following conjecture correct?

**Conjecture**. The divisibility condition $(\alpha+\beta)^2 \mid (2\beta^3+6\alpha\beta^2-1)$ has no solutions in positive integers $1 \le \beta < \alpha < 2\beta$.

This question is related to finding integer points on a Mordell curve. A computer search outside the range indicated turned up the expected single solution $(a,b)=(4,1)$ [corresponding to the single integer point on the original Mordell curve], as well as an unexpected solution $(\alpha,\beta)=(11364,46061)$, which I can't explain. Any insights would be appreciated.

I believe a method of solution — particularly by descent — to this special case would be immediately applicable to a large class of elliptic curves.

FWIW, I've developed a partial proof which I include below. The Vieta jump implies that, for any solution $(a,b)$, there is a rational solution $(b,\tfrac{6b^2}{k}-2b-a)$ with the same $k$; in the case of the one known solution $(a,b)=(4,1)$, we do have $k=1$ in the original equation
$$
  (5b-a+1)(a+b)^2 = 2(2b^3+6ab^2-1),
$$
which makes the second Vieta root degenerate at $(1,0)$.

---

**Proof** (incomplete). The divisibility hypothesis implies
\begin{equation}
 k(\alpha+\beta)^2 = 2\beta^3+6\alpha\beta^2-1,  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
for an integer $k \ge 1$. Rearranging (1) and replacing $\alpha$ with the variable $\xi$ yields
\begin{equation*}
 k\xi^2 + 2\beta(k-3\beta)\xi + (k\beta^2-2\beta^3+1) = 0.%  \label{EQ: solve this}
\end{equation*}
One root of this equation is $\xi_1 = \alpha$. By Vieta's formulas, the other root may be written as
\begin{align}
 \xi_2 &= \frac{2\beta(3\beta-k)}{k} - \alpha = \frac{\beta^2(k-2\beta)+1}{k \alpha}.  \tag{2}
\end{align}

First, assume $\xi_2$ is an integer. Since $\alpha$ is an integer, the first relation in (2) implies that the fraction must also be an integer. Hence $k \mid 6\beta^2$. But (1) implies both that $k$ is odd, and that $\gcd(k,\beta)=1$. Hence $k \mid 3$, so $k = 1$ or $3$. If $k = 3$, then the second relation in (2) implies that $\xi_2$ is positive when $\beta = 1$, and negative when $\beta > 1$. On the other hand, the first relation with $k=3$ gives $\xi_2 = 2\beta(\beta-1) - \alpha$. When $\beta = 1$, this implies $0 < \xi_2 = 2\beta(\beta-1) - \alpha = -\alpha$, contradicting $\alpha > 0$. When $\beta > 1$, we have $0 > \xi_2 = 2\beta(\beta-1) - \alpha$. Hence $\alpha > 2\beta(\beta-1)$, contradicting $\alpha < 2\beta$.
**END OF PARTIAL PROOF**

Note that the unexpected solution $(\alpha,\beta)=(11364,46061)$ implies
\begin{equation*}
 k = \frac{2\beta^3+6\alpha\beta^2-1}{(\alpha+\beta)^2} = \frac{340107729770625}{3297630625} = 3 \cdot 31 \cdot 1109,
\end{equation*}
and then we have
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{2\beta(3\beta-k)}{k} - \alpha = \frac{\beta^2(k-2\beta)+1}{k \alpha} = \frac{685486248}{34379}
\end{equation*}
not an integer.

Comment: Why do you think the conjecture is true?

Comment: Maxima brute-force calculations, mostly. A different form of it might be true: If $\alpha > \beta$ satisfies the hypothesis, then the quotient is $1$ __or__ $\alpha > 2(\beta+1)$. I'd also be happy to have a counterexample found.

Comment: As I said in the MSE thread, the exact equation I'm trying to solve can be written as $(5b-a+1)(a+b)^2=2(2b^3+6ab^2-1)$, and I happen to know, based on how I derived this form, that the only solution is $(a,b)=(4,1)$. But I'm interested in figuring out a _general method_ to attack this class of divisibility problems.

Comment: See also the meta thread: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1865/why-is-my-question-apparently-not-research-level

Comment: Kieren, I hope you don't mind the edit. I just wanted to make sure the post was in the form of a question.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a reformulation of the conjecture, and a heuristic which suggests that the conjecture is false.  Note that $a+b$ must be odd.  Put $\ell = a+b$  (and $\ell$ is odd) and $m=a-b$ which is also odd.  The condition that $b<a<2b$ now translates to $0<m < \ell/3$.  The divisibility condition of the question translates nicely to the condition $\ell^2$ divides $m^3-2$.

So the question really is can $m^3-2$ have a square factor of size exceeding $(3m)^2$?   Here's a heuristic that indicates why this should be possible.  Given $\ell$ odd, the number of solutions $\pmod {\ell^2}$ to $x^3-2\equiv 0 \pmod{\ell^2}$ is given by a multiplicative function $f(\ell)$.  Here if $p\ge 5$ then $f(p^k)$ is simply the number of solutions to $x^3\equiv 2 \pmod p$ which is $0$, $1$ or $3$ (with asymptotic densities as in Chebotarev).  For $p=3$ one should work a tiny bit harder.  Then the question is whether one of these $f(\ell)$ solutions $\pmod{\ell^2}$ happens to lie below $\ell/3$.  We may expect that probability to be about $f(\ell)/(3\ell)$.  Thus the expected number of $\ell$ below $x$ for which $\ell^2$ divides $m^3-2$ (with $m< \ell/3$) should be about 
$$ 
\sum_{\ell < x; \ell \text{ odd}} f(\ell)/(3\ell) \sim C \log x,
$$ 
for some positive constant $C$ -- with a little calculation, using the Dedekind zeta function one should be able to calculate $C$.   This suggests that there are infinitely many counterexamples.

I didn't find any with $m$ below $10000$ (I searched for large square factors of $m^3-2$), but my guess would be that there is a reasonable chance of finding counterexamples with $m$ in the millions, and a very good chance if $m$ is in the billions.

Added:  A relevant paper for such problems is Granville's [paper](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/hyperelliptics.pdf) in IMRN.
Granville shows that on the abc conjecture the largest square factor of any cubic polynomial (without repeated roots) $f(m)$ is at most $m^{2+o(1)}$.  This generalizes the observation in GH from MO's answer (the general case requires more work than the easy $x^3-2$ example).  Granville also gives reasons to believe that this exponent is best possible, and in particular shows that such large square factors are attained for cubic polynomials having a rational root -- this uses the solutions to Pell's equation.  Of course, Granville's construction doesn't apply for $x^3-2$ which is irreducible, but the results may be suggestive.  Also note that the Pell type constructions produce a logarithmic number of examples with large square factors, which is again suggestive.

Comment: I made your heuristic a bit more specific, and performed more extensive experiments. See my added section

Comment: @GHfromMO:  That's very nice!  If we think of a Poisson process, then maybe one expects to find no counterexample around size $10^{10}$ with probability $1/e$, and finding no counterexample of size $10^{20}$ with probability $1/e^2$ etc.  Also, I'm not completely sure of the numerical value you give for $C$ -- maybe a typo somewhere?  (If $C$ is really as big as $0.4$ wouldn't you expect counterexamples sooner?)

Comment: I think the value for $C$ is ok. The initial factors $1/6$, $1/2$, $2/3$ should be clear, while the product over $p>3$ is very close to $1$. The residue of the Dedekind zeta function is $2\pi h_K R_K/|D_K|^{1/2}$ with the usual notation. We have $h_K=1$, $R_K\approx 1.347$, $D_K=-108$. On the other hand, I was wrong saying that any interval of additive length $\approx\exp(1/C)$ should have an $\ell$. Instead, any interval of multiplicative length $\approx\exp(1/C)$ should have one. This means that realistically the first counterexample can be as large as $10^{20}$!

Comment: @GHfromMO:  Your values seem to give $C$ more like $0.04$ rather than $0.4$?  (I mean the $C$ in the $C \log x$ of my answer.)  This is why I thought there may be a typo there.

Comment: Sure, that was a typo, thanks for spotting it!

Comment: I have now found a pair with $m/\ell\approx 0.766$! See my added section.

Comment: We are now at $m/\ell\approx 0.485$ which is smaller than all previous ratios, including the one for $(\ell,m)=(5,3)$.

Answer (score 20):

This is a supplement to Lucia's answer. His/her heuristic analysis suggests that there are infinitely many odd $m$'s such that the largest square dividing $m^3-2$ exceeds $9m^2$, contradicting the conjecture.

On the other hand, the abc conjecture implies that the largest square dividing $m^3-2$ is $\ll_\epsilon m^{2+\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$, which indicates that a slightly weaker version of the conjecture (i.e. one with a more restrictive constraint on the variables) is probably true.

Some calculations with SAGE show that for $m<10^7$ there are only two instances where the largest square dividing $m^3-2$ exceeds $m^2$, namely $m=3$ and $m=100$. (Noam Elkies extended the range to $m<\ell<10^8$ with a more efficient gp-pari code.) I found five further values with a square divisor exceeding $m^2/2$, and these are $\{1244,11317,296428,714417,722428\}$.

**Added.** The constant in Lucia's heuristic analysis (with $m$ restricted to odd numbers) equals
$$ \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\prod_{\substack{p>3\\f(p)=0}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^3}\right)\prod_{\substack{p>3\\f(p)=1}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)\prod_{\substack{p>3\\f(p)=3}}\left(1-\frac{3}{p^2}+\frac{2}{p^3}\right)$$
times the residue of the Dedekind zeta function of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)$. The initial factor $1/6$ accounts for Lucia's denominator $3$ and the fact that we only look for odd $m$'s. The other factors come from comparing the Euler factors of $\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty f(\ell)\ell^{-s}$ to those of the Dedekind zeta function. My calculation in SAGE shows that
$ C\approx 0.0423$, which suggests that the average ratio between the consecutive $\ell$'s yielding a counterexample $(\ell,m)$ is about $1.867\times 10^{10}$.

**Summary of ongoing calculation.** Counterexamples to the OP's conjecture correspond bijectively to pairs of odd numbers $(\ell,m)$ such that $\ell^2\mid m^3-2$ and $m/\ell<1/3$.
I extended Noam Elkies' gp-pari calculation to the range $\ell<10^{12}$ and am checking higher ranges on several machines. The best pairs I found so far (allowing $m$ even) are 
$$(\ell,m)=(10444012561, 5062142741)\quad\text{with ratio}\quad m/\ell\approx 0.485$$
$$(\ell,m)=(22713683537, 7950843140)\quad\text{with ratio}\quad m/\ell\approx 0.350$$
In particular, these beat the basic ratio $m/\ell=0.600$ that corresponds to $(\ell,m)=(5,3)$.

Comment: Very interesting! I'm familiar with $\ll$ but not $\ll_\epsilon$. What is the meaning?

Comment: $x\ll_\epsilon y$ means that there is a constant $c_\epsilon$ depending only on $\epsilon$ such that $|x|\leq c_\epsilon y$. Another notation for the same relation is $x=O_\epsilon(y)$.

Comment: Note that the heuristic I gave also suggests that apart from finitely many exceptions, the largest square factor of $m^3-2$ is at most $(m\log m)^2$, say.  So this is certainly in a very delicate range!

Comment: @Lucia: Yes. Also, there are refinements of the abc conjecture that can make the $m^{2+\epsilon}$ bound more precise.

Comment: It's faster to look for $\ell^2 \mid m^3 - 2$ via the factorization of
$\ell$ rather than $m^3-2$.  A 30 minute calulation in **gp**
(using **polrootspadic**) finds that
there are no examples of $m<\ell$ with $\ell$ odd and  $0 < \ell < 10^8$
besides the known $(\ell,m) = (5,3)$ and $(127,100)$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: This is a good idea, thank you! I am using a very simple 3-line code in SAGE, utilizing the function squarefree_part. Can you post your code, e.g. as part of a response here? I could learn from it as I am not at all familiar with gp.

Comment: OK, **gp** code follows, though I'm afraid the line breaks and indentations
will be lost $-$ or is there a way to retain such formatting in comments?
$$ $$
**L = 10^8;
{
forstep(l=3,L,2,
 if(l%10^6==1,print("<",l-1,">"));
 if(l%3,
  F = factor(l);
  n = #F[,1];
  v = vector(n,i,polrootspadic(x^3-2,F[i,1],2*F[i,2]));
  for(i=1,n, v[i] = lift(v[i]) * Mod(1,F[i,1]^(2*F[i,2])));
  forvec(r=vector(n,i,[1,#v[i]]),
    m = Mod(0,1);
    for(i=1,n, m=chinese(m,v[i][r[i]]));
    m = lift(m);
    if(m<l,print([l,m]))
    )
  )
 )
}**

Comment: [The condition **if(l%3,** (i.e., don't try $\ell$ if $3\mid\ell$)
exploits the fact that $x^3-2$ has no roots mod $3^2$.  I could have
also saved a factor of nearly $3/4$ by requiring that $\ell$ not be
divisible by $7$, $13$, or $19$.]

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Thank you for the code!

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: I am stretching your range with your program, in the hope of hitting a counterexample. See my added section. Perhaps you have access to faster computers.

Comment: Using your code, I found a new example with $\ell^2 \mid m^3 - 2$ and $\ell>m$: $(\ell,m)=(3230984317,2474621651)$. A pleasant feature is that $m$ is odd and $m/\ell\approx 0.766$ is significantly below $1$.

Comment: A counterexample would be $< 0.333...$, am I correct?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: Yes. I am sure it exists, but it might be as large as $10^{16}$, for which a supercomputer would be needed. I was already surprised by finding a pair with ratio $0.766$.

Comment: If I can push my algebraic proof a little further, I might be able to get a bound on the quotient $k$, which would help reduce [possibly significantly] the number of tests required.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: I don't know how to make use of any information on the quotient. What Noam's code does is: it cycles over $\ell$, and for each $\ell$ it finds the smallest $m$ such that $\ell^2\mid m^3-2$.

Comment: Well, for example, I think I could invert the current proof, and show that $k \ge 5$. So that would, I think, mean you're looking for a ratio $m/\ell \le 0.2$, yes? So your bound on $m$ for a given $\ell$ would be almost cut in half.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: Smaller ratios for $m/\ell$ are harder to find. Please do not change your conjecture to make it harder for us to disprove :-)

Comment: I think $k$ is a about size $b$, which is roughly $\ell-m$.  Knowing that this is at least $5$ doesn't help, or hurt, the computations of GH from MO.  In the notation of the original question, GH from MO's computations have disproved the conjecture if the condition had been $b<a<8b$.

Comment: According to your original transformation, isn't $b=(\ell-m)/2$? And why do you think $k \approx b$?

Comment: @GHfromMO: In your original answer, you suggested that the abc conjecture would imply a slightly _weaker_ conjecture is “probably true”. If you find a counterexample to my stronger conjecture, what will that say??

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: One counterexample does not tell much, beyond disproving your conjecture of course. Infinitely many counterexamples would tell that the abc conjecture cannot be strengthened in a certain way. At any rate, here is a conjecture that I believe is true and would yield infinitely many counterexamples to your conjecture (continued in next comment):

Comment: Consider the odd pairs $(\ell,m)$ satisfying $\ell^2\mid m^3-2$. Then the ratios $m/\ell$ are equidistributed in $(0,\infty)$ in a certain sense (I can be more specific if you wish). In particular, the ratios $m/\ell$ are dense in $(0,\infty)$, hence they are infinitely often smaller than $1/3$.

Comment: 0.350... You're getting close! But you should consider writing explicitly in your answer, near the numerical examples, that an example with $m/l < 0.333$ would be a counter-example to the original OP's conjecture. Right now a new reader has to read carefully Lucia's answer or the comment on yours to find this information.

Comment: Note that the $\approx 0.350$ example doesn't have $\ell,m$ odd, so it's not a candidate. The hypothetical counterexample record still stands at $\approx 0.485$.

Comment: @Joël: Thanks for your comment. I will update the text accordingly.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: Yes, this is why I kept the previous example of $0.485$ as well.

Comment: Are there any updates? Have you reached a technical limit on the search for counterexamples?

Comment: I have checked all $\ell<10^{12}$ by distributing the task between many machines. This is quite a big range. I will continue the search for another week, month, or year (depending when I get tired), and I will post a summary then. At the moment all I can say is that the data is in good agreement with Lucia's heuristic.

Comment: @GHfromMO: Just checking in on progress. Would love to see whatever data you've already got, etc.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: Sorry, I got busy with other things and the remote computers I used were rebooted regularly, so I stopped checking. I covered all $\ell<2.1\times 10^{12}$ though, and found no counterexample. In this range, I recorded all triples $(\ell,m,m/\ell)$ with $\ell^2\mid m^3-2$ and $m/\ell<50$. I found 421 such triples, and among them the fractions $m/\ell$ distribute very uniformly: if we order these by size in Excel, their histogram is almost a perfect line. So all the empirical and theoretical evidence suggests that there is a counterexample, but I did not find one.

Comment: @GHfromMO: I'd appreciate it if you could email me your results (see my profile for address). Thanks!

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: Mail sent!

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can, except for your one case of $(b,j)=(1,2)$, change the bounds to $300+1 \lt b \lt a \lt 2b-300.$ The number $300$ could easily be made as large as you please (unless a counter-example to your conjecture turned up) because each $j$ only allows a few possible pairs $a=2b+j$ and these can be checked. That does not prove anything but the method is simple and might interest you.

Pick a particular $j$ (and you have assumed $j \le 2$), set $a=2b+j$ and consider first the weaker condition that $a+b \mid 2b^3+6ab^2-1$ which becomes $3b+j \mid 14b^3+6b^2j-1$. Any common divisor of those two must also divide $14b^2(3b+j)-3(14b^3+6b^2j-1)=-4b^2j+3.$ Continuing in this fashion we see that any common divisor must divide $27-4j^3.$ So

- find all the divisors of $27-4j^3$ of the form $3k+j$
- For each set $b=k,a=2k-j$ and, provided that $b \lt a$ check if indeed  $3b+j \mid 14b^3+6b^2j-1$.
- On the rare occasions that that happens check the actual desired condition that  $(3b+j)^2 \mid 14b^3+6b^2j-1$.

For $-30 \le j \le 2$ the pairs $[b,j]$ which survive until the last test are

$[2671, -28], [5865, -28], [451, -26], [3254, -23], [625, -22],$$ [843, -22], [322, -19], [179, -18], [602, -17], [18, -13],$$ [76, -13], [592, -13], [11, -8], [141, -8], [12, -5], [1, 2]$

But only $[1,2]$ survives the last step.

I checked as far as $j=-300.$